# Slow for loop, loading images from a Parse query into an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, query-performance

Here is my code, I am having issues with it. It works, however it takes a very long time to load. I have the code within viewDidLoad. Also the self.playedGames and self.messages are NSArrays I got from querying two other classes.

```
newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[self.playedGames count]];
messagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[self.messages count]];
ImageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[self.playedGames count]];
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query orderByDescending:@"username"];

NSArray *Userarray1 = [query findObjects];
//NSLog(@"Userarray1 = %@",Userarray1);

PFFile *imageFile = [[PFFile alloc]init];
NSURL *imageFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc]init];
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]init];
for(id i in Userarray1){
    userPerson = [i valueForKey:@"username"];

    for(id object in self.messages){
        if([[object objectForKey:@"senderName"]isEqualToString:userPerson]){
            imageFile = [i objectForKey:@"profilePic"];



            if(imageFile !=nil){
                imageFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:imageFile.url];

                imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileUrl];
                newImageset = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                PFImageView *imgVew = [[PFImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 50, 50)];
                imgVew.image = newImageset;
                imgVew.opaque = YES;
                [messagesArray addObject:imgVew];

            }
            else{
                UIImage *NoPP = [UIImage imageNamed:@"friends_tab.png"];
                NoPP = [self imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
                PFImageView *NoPPView = [[PFImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 50, 50)];
                NoPPView.image = NoPP;
                NoPPView.opaque = YES;
                [messagesArray addObject:NoPPView];

            }
        }
    }

    //step two
    for(id object in self.playedGames){
        if([[object objectForKey:@"yourName"] isEqualToString:userPerson]){
            imageFile = [i objectForKey:@"profilePic"];

            if(imageFile !=nil){
                imageFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:imageFile.url];

                imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileUrl];
                newImageset = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                PFImageView *imgVew = [[PFImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 50, 50)];
                imgVew.image = newImageset;
                imgVew.opaque = YES;
                [ImageArray addObject:imgVew];
                //NSLog(@"ImageArray = %@",ImageArray);


            }
            else{
                UIImage *NoPP = [UIImage imageNamed:@"friends_tab.png"];
                NoPP = [self imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
                PFImageView *NoPPView = [[PFImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 50, 50)];
                NoPPView.image = NoPP;
                NoPPView.opaque = YES;
                [ImageArray addObject:NoPPView];

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two really big problems.

1. The `[query findObjects];` is synchronous, meaning that it does not return until complete. This needs to happen in the background. Take a look at one of the findInBackground methods offered by Parse.
2. Within your loop, you are loading image resource from a URL by calling `imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileUrl];`. Again, this is synchronous and will wait until one image is loaded before moving on to the next. These image loads need to be made asynchronous as well.

Comment: How can i make the imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileUrl]; asynchronous?

Comment: do i do fetchDataInBackground?

Answer (score 0):

worked around it and added this

```
NSURL *imageFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:imageFile.url];
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
                            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileUrl];
                            newImageset = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                                PFImageView *imgVew = [[PFImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 50, 50)];
                                imgVew.image = newImageset;
                                imgVew.opaque = YES;
                                [messagesArray addObject:imgVew];
                            });
                            loadingthesearches1 = YES;
                            [self ReloadTheData];
                        });
```

and it worked 90% faster

Comment: That's much better. Don't forget to replace the findObjects as well.